# 9. Palindrome Number(leetcode) issues with correct results

Tags: python

I'm newbie at coding. So, recently I faced with problems with test inputs in Palendrome number. Here's my code

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
        str_x = str(x)
        list_x = []
        for i in str_x:
            list_x.append(i)
        new_x = ((''.join(map(str, list_x[::-1]))))
        if str(x) == str(new_x):
            return('true')
        elif str(x) != (new_x) :
            return('false')
```

If I input all values manually in VCS, 10 of 10 i will get correct result.
Actually, what details have i missed?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Let aside the fact that your code is doing a lot of useless things, shouldn't you return a boolean `True`/`False`? Not a string `"true"`/"false"

Comment: Your return value is not correct, you return a string not a bool :D

Comment: I see. Thank you for help. Sorry for my inadvertence. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has already been answered. You need to use booleans, instead of strings, in your return.

But, I wanted to add some code that might make things easier to understand:

```py
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
        str_x = str(x) # This is fine, but can be added in the list comprehension below
        
        list_x = [char for char in str_x] # Nice to use clear names
        new_x = ''.join(map(str, list_x[::-1]))

        return str_x == new_x # Cleaner way return true / false
```